# Hiding a div or appending it dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a register/login form. My current design is as follows

```
 <div class="container">
    <form class="register">
    </form>
    <form class="login">
    </form>
 </div>
```

I am using `Jquery` to `show/hide` divs.

Another approach could be

```
  <div class="container">
      //Empty Div
  </div>
```

`Append/Remove` divs dynamically when user clicks `register/login` button.

Which one is the best over anohter? What are the pros and cons of these methods.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Best how? What's your criteria? As is stands now your question is opinion-based.

Comment: It is personal opinion. Showing/Hiding seems more reasonable since you do not have to worry about where the content is going to be loaded from. BUT if the content was huge, loading it dynamically is probably a better bet. So the answer is it depends.

Comment: Do `hide/show`, I don't think it is necessary to dynamically remove and add each one.

Comment: My page has a lot of contents. But login/register div doesn't matter with page contents. If i am wrong correct me. But what i assumed was creating divs dynamically will be slower than show/hide.

Comment: @GopsAB That's correct.

Answer (score 1):

I think appending/removing the divs would be the worst solution because that would clear the state of the forms.. Like.. The user would lose information if he/she decided to go from one form to the other. But generally, they are both acceptable.

Comment: Yes you cleared My doubt with single point `Would Lose Info`. Will you please tell me if it is not login div, what could be the best. plus one

Comment: You can design it so the info is saved.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek i am asking about other divs. For example, If user selects `Australia` it should show `Aus info` and if it is `NZ`, then container should have `NZ info`. For these kinda things, `Removing/Adding` is the best i guess. Am i correct?

Comment: @GopsAB I think either way would be fine, I would agree *removing/adding* seems like a good choice.